# ORA-00928: missing SELECT keyword when using with clause

Tags: sql, oracle

My SQL query is:

```
with temp1 (hacker_id, chlng_cnt) as 
(
     select hacker_id, count(challenge_id) as chlng_cnt 
     from Challenges 
     group by hacker_id
);
```

where the table `Challenges` has this schema:

```
Challenges(hacker_id, challenge_id)
```

I don't see any mistake with my query, I have used the `select` keyword. So why am I getting this error?

Comment: you miss the followup select/insert/update/delete statement after `CTE` [MySQL CTE syntax](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-cte/) will may help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
with temp1 as 
(select hacker_id, count(challenge_id) as chlng_cnt from Challenges group by hacker_id)
select *  from temp1
```

You missed "select" after with

Comment: do I need to select directly from the temporary relation? can't I use this for something else and select from that. I was actually using temp1 to create another temporary relation using with clause

Comment: @Shantanu Shinde Why you write ";" after with statement? if you used a few temporary "select" use ","